# JBoss Application Errors

Tags: java, jboss

I am working on a JBoss 4.0.5 app and I am encountering a problem with servlets. Whenever I modify anything in .JAVA file the result isn't visible in the browser.

Say there is a functionality which inserts a new row in "category" table of PostgreSQL database and there is a column named "Title". The Title variable is being gotten from the text box and when I modify this variable to something like...

```
String Title = "With Jboss Servlet Updated " + UserInputTitle;
```

Although it does enter the record in the database but there is not concatenated string starting from "With Jboss Servlet Updated ". I am totally lost figuring this out.

Here's my console data and I am writing errors and so on. http://typewith.me/ep/pad/view/ro.rGpg01GQjFj/rev.2

Answer (score 1):

You can't just modify the java source and expect the changes to be reflected in the running application.  You need to recompile, repackage the application, and redeploy to JBoss.

Comment: Yes I know it. I restart the Jboss everytime I change in it and it was working fine few weeks ago. This is sudden reaction.

Comment: @Umair: Fair enough, but you need to tell us these things in the question.